# Importing deprecated statements in Wikidata

Tags: wikidata, openrefine

I read that [Openrefine Wikidata import can only create statements with rank = Normal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Tools/OpenRefine/Editing/Schema_alignment#Ranks).

I am in a situation where I would like to import deprecated identifiers, namely old ISSNs (identifiers for serial publications) that used to be used to refer to a publication, but that are no longer in use. They have value because other bibliographic databases might still use them to refer to a publication.

So I'd like to be able to import these values, and mark them as "deprecated".

1. OpenRefine Wikidata import really really can't do that ? any workaround I could use ?
2. If I can't do that by the time I import the data from OpenRefine, I can [flag these statements with "reason for deprecation = withdrawn identifier value"](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Deprecation#Reason_for_deprecation). Can I run another automated process after import that would automatically set a deprecated rank on these statements ?
3. If I can't set them automatically to deprecated neither at import time nor after, which other qualifier can I use to indicated these identifiers are no longer in use ? (the official term being "Cancelled ISSN")

Thanks

Comment: Its too bad that you cannot use Quickstatements, that would be fairly easy to set the "rank = deprecated".  But alas, [Quickstatements v2 does not support setting ranks for statements.](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:QuickStatements#Limitations)

Comment: @ThadGuidry : I am open to any tool suggestion, but as you said, QuickStatements does not seem to support this. Could the rank of these statements, once imported, be updated by a bot or a script ?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility I found would be to use the [Wikidata-Toolkit library](https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit), in which [StatementBuilder can create Statements with a specified rank](https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit/blob/7d28daa5321fa11c2718fdc05835931db3ac1cb9/wdtk-datamodel/src/main/java/org/wikidata/wdtk/datamodel/helpers/StatementBuilder.java#L92). I would still to know/fetch the list of statements to modify...

I am still open to suggestions on the possibility to specify ranks at import time.